# C#でCSVファイルへの出力

Tags: c#, windows

C#でテキストボックスに表示された文字をCドライブ直下に出力したいのですがどうもうまくいきません。。
どなたかご教授いただければ幸いです。

```
using (var w = new System.IO.StreamWriter("test.csv", false, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("shift_jis")))
{
    w.Write(textBox.Text);
    w.Close();
｝
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C:ドライブ直下にファイルを出力したいのであれば`StreamWriter`作成時に`C:\test.csv`のように完全パスを指定してください。ファイル名のみを指定した場合、通常はカレントディレクトリ＝実行ファイルのある場所に出力されることになります。

なお`C:\test.csv`を定数で表す場合、`"C:\\test.csv"`と`\`を重ねるか、`@"C:\test.csv"`と先頭に@をつける必要があります。

また`using (w)`内では`w.Close()`を呼ぶ必要はありません。

Answer (score 4):

> Cドライブ直下に出力したい

Windowsでは通常権限でのCドライブ直下への書き込みは禁止されています。
正確には Usersグループ には書き込み権限が与えられておらず、Administratorsグループには与えられていますがUAC昇格（管理者で実行）が必要となっています。

Cドライブ直下は使用しないようアプリケーションを設計することをお勧めします。

Comment: わかりました。ありがとうございました